# UDP client now listening if server has send muliple ip

Tags: udp, udpclient

Currently i have facing one problem in portrestrictedcone nattype.When my udp client hit the server with test1.dns.com (to sepcific IP 111.111.111.111 and this ip is bind with DNS test1.dns.com) where i am getting response from different IP and not with 111.111.111.111, however the same scenario is working for fullcone nattype. If the server response from the same above ip i am able to get the response.

Currently there are two services running on the server on UDP, one is which is working in portrestrictedcone and send response on same IP as a result i am getting the response, however second service is not behaving in same was as first service works.

i am running both the services on same DNS as i have describe above.

Can i get the help what i need to change on the server or client side to get this resolve?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are not sending the packet to the port you received it from (Allocated by NAT). When you receive a packet, check the port that was used to send it then send your response to that port and not to a predefined port because the NAT might change it.